# Performance and data manipulation on Dask

Tags: dask

I have imported a parquet file of approx. 800MB with ~50 millions rows into dask dataframe.
There are 5 columns: `DATE, TICKER, COUNTRY, RETURN, GICS`

Questions:

1. How can I specify data type in read_parquet or I have to do it with astype?
2. Can I parse date within read_parquet
3. I simply tried to do the follow:

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   dd.read_parquet('.\abc.gzip')
   df['INDUSTRY'] = df.GICS.str[0:4]
   n = df.INDUSTRY.unique().compute()
   ```

   and it takes forever to return. Am I doing anything wrong here? partitions are automatically set to 1.

I am trying to do something like `df[df.INDUSTRY == '4010'].compute()`, it also takes forever to return or crash.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

1. A parquet file has types stored, as noted in the Apache docs [here](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/), thus you won't be able to change the data type when you read the file in, meaning you'll have to use `astype`.
2. You can't convert a string to date within a the read, though if you use the `map_partitions` function, documented [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions) you can convert the column to date, as in this example:

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   df = dd.read_parquet(your_file)
   meta = ('date', 'datetime64[ns]')
   # you can add your own date format, or just let pandas guess
   to_date_time = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d')
   df['date_clean'] = df.date.map_partitions(to_date_time, meta=meta)
   ```

   The `map_partitions` function will convert the dates on each chunk of the parquet when the file is computed, making it functionally the same as converting the date when the file is read in.
3. Here I think again you would benefit from using the `map_partitions` function, so you might try something like this

   ```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   df = dd.read_parquet('.\abc.gzip')
   df['INDUSTRY']df.GICS.map_partitions(lambda x: x.str[0:4], meta=('INDUSTRY', 'str'))
   df[df.INDUSTRY == '4010']
   ```

   Note that if you run `compute` the object is converted to pandas. If the file is too large than Dask won't be able to compute it, and thus nothing will be returned. Without seeing the data it's harder to say more, but do checkout [these tools](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html) to profile your computations to see if you are leveraging all your CPUs.